# I have problem in ios device that i put loadin but that is not run

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ios, iphone

I display a loading gif on an event. This gif animated well on Android platforms but does not animated on the iPhone. I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

```js
var inpFile = document.getElementById("file-input");
var gif = document.getElementById("demo-loading-web");

inpFile.addEventListener("change", function() {
  gif.style.display = "block";
  localStorage.setItem('show', 'true');
})

window.onload = function() {
  var show = localStorage.getItem('show');
  if (show === 'true') {
    gif.style.display = "none";
    var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
    if (perfEntries[0].type === "back_forward") {
      location.reload(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say 'the gif doesn't run', do you mean that the gif is not displayed at all, or that it is displayed, but is not animated? If the latter then the issue is how the file has been saved.

Comment: sorry for my wrong question,the Gif was disabled but not animated on Iphone